# Pandas: Optimal subtract every nth row

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I'm writing a function for a special case of row-wise subtraction in pandas.

- First the user should be able to specify rows either by regex (i.e. "_BL[0-9]+") or by regular index i.e every 6th row
- Then we must subtract every matching row from rows preceding it, but not past another match
- [Optionally] Drop selected rows
- Column to match on should be user-defined by either index or label

For example if:

| Samples | var1 | var1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| something | 10 | 20 |
| something | 20 | 30 |
| something | 40 | 30 |
| **some_BL20_thing** | 100 | 100 |
| something | 50 | 70 |
| something | 90 | 100 |
| **some_BL10_thing** | 100 | 10 |

Expected output should be:

| Samples | var1 | var1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| something | -90 | -80 |
| something | -80 | -70 |
| something | -60 | -70 |
| something | -50 | 60 |
| something | -10 | 90 |

My current (incomplete) implementation relies heavily on looping:

```
def subtract_blanks(data:pd.DataFrame, num_samples:int)->pd.DataFrame:
    '''
        Accepts a data dataframe and a mod int and 
        subtracts each blank from all mod preceding samples
    '''
    expr = compile(r'(_BL[0-9]{1})')
    output = data.copy(deep = True)
    for idx,row in output.iterrows():
        if search(expr,row['Sample']):
            for i in range(1,num_samples+1):
                output.iloc[idx-i,data_start:] = output.iloc[idx-i,6:]-row.iloc[6:]
    return output
```

Is there a better way of doing this? This implementation seems pretty ugly. I've also considered maybe splitting the DataFrame to chucks and operating on them instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

```
# Create boolean mask for matching rows
# m = np.arange(len(df)) % 6 == 5 # for index match
m = df['Samples'].str.contains(r'_BL\d+') # for regex match

# mask the values and backfill to propagate the row
# values corresponding to match in backward direction
df['var1'] = df['var1'] - df['var1'].mask(~m).bfill()

# Delete the matching rows
df = df[~m].copy()
```

---

```
     Samples  var1  var1
0  something -90.0 -80.0
1  something -80.0 -70.0
2  something -60.0 -70.0
4  something -50.0  60.0
5  something -10.0  90.0
```

Note: The core logic is specified in the `code` so I'll leave the function implementation upto the OP.

Comment: The `df.mask(~m).bfill()` solution is very elegant, though I had to use `np.repeat` and `np.reshape` to operate of the entire DataFrame, instead of column-wise.